# Why doesn't "numpy.random.random((a,b))" work?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a matrix that creates a matrix of size a*b.

```
numpy.random.random((2,3)) #this works and creates a matrix of size 2,3
```

But,

```
m = input("Enter M: ")
n = input("Enter N: ")
o = input("Enter O: ")

A = numpy.random.random((m,n))
B = numpy.random.random((n,o))
```

why doesnt this work??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the type of `m,n` and `o` is `str`. You need to add `int` around `input`, as follows:

```
import numpy
m = int(input("Enter M: "))
n = int(input("Enter N: "))
o = int(input("Enter O: "))

A = numpy.random.random((m,n))
B = numpy.random.random((n,o))
```